# how to make associations between grand parent & parent & child in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 4 tabels

- stores
- categories
- items
- item_images

Now i want to make association between them categories have store_id foreign key and items table have category_id and item_images have item_id foreign key.

```
   public $hasMany = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'className'    => 'Item',
        'foreignKey'   => 'category_id'
    ));
```

The above association is for category that find the related items but i want to do associate it with item_images. How i can do it with item_images now?

In Controller i have this query

```
$storeCategoriesDetails = $this->Category->find("all", array('conditions' => array('Category.storeId' => $id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to put your association for the `item_images` on the `Item` model like you've done for `items` on the `Category` model. You can then retrieve the item images along with the items when retrieving categories using `contain`:-

```
$storeCategoriesDetails = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Item' => array('ItemImage'))
    'conditions' => array('Category.storeId' => $id)
));
```

Comment: i have done it like in Item.php   
 public $hasMany = array(
    'ItemImage' => array(
        'className'    => 'ItemImage',
        'foreignKey'   => 'itemId'
    ));

Comment: What is not working? Have you checked the queries your `find` call is generating?

Comment: yes but it's not giving me the item_images only category & items are coming

Comment: Make sure your relationships are all correct. You may need to check the `recursive` setting on the `ContainableBehavior`. I'd recommend reading through the [official docs on Containable](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations).

Comment: i'm using it             $storeDetail = $this->Category->find("all", array(
                'contain' => array('Item' => array('ItemImage')),
                'conditions' => array('Category.storeId' => $id)
                )); and Model for items i sent you above but it's not showing any thing.

Comment: only category and items are coming in data not itemImage

Answer (score 0):

I added this line in my controller function and it's working now.

```
$this->Category->Behaviors->load('Containable');
```